# In List view, can the Files prog on iOS 15.2 list files without showing icons and without showing dates and sizes on the same line as each file name?

Tags: ios, files.app

When I run the Files program on iOS 15.2 and choose "List view", it lists files with each file name having a small icon to the left of it and with the date and file size shown below it. There are also horizontal lines separating each file's entry from the next file's. This allows 11 files to be shown at a time on the screen of my iPhone XR without scrolling being necessary.

If no icons were shown, and the dates and file sizes were shown either on the same line as the file names or not at all, then the number of files that could be listed without scrolling being necessary would be much larger, perhaps as great as 20.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question of myself a few weeks ago and could not find any settings that customized this view at all. We get what we see: no less; no more.

You can always submit [Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/) to Apple and describe your design enhancements in the comments field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get more files in a screen without scrolling in list view but the solution is not to remove the icons or the infos, it's to reduce the text size.

By default, the text size of all apps is set to be 100% but you can change that for every specific app. If you change Files text size from 100% (default) to 80% (minimum), you get more files to show.

To do this, you can go to **Settings** > **Accessibility** > **Per-App Settings** > **Add App** > **Files** > **Files** > **Larger Text**. Then drag the white circle to the minimum (at the very left of the scale). But you can also do this in a much more simple way: Open Control Center by (1) swiping down from the top-right corner of your screen (for iPhones with Home Bar) or (2) swiping up from the bottom of your screen (for iPhone with Home Button); then, click on "<sub>A</sub>A"*, check that the blue circle is on top of "Files only", and drag the white bars to the minimum (down) so that the text size is set to 80%.

[image: Screenshot of the iPhone's Control Center] [image: Screenshot to the Text Size adjustment control]

[image: Screenshot of a folder listing in Files before the text size change] [image: Screenshot of a folder listing in Files after the text size change]

<sup>*</sup> To be able to click on "<sub>A</sub>A", you will need to check in **Settings** > **Control Center** that **Text Size** is in the **Included Controls** section.